# Does PHP-FPM supports FastCGI multi-plexing at a protocol level?

Tags: php, fastcgi

FastCGI the protocol includes provisions for multi-plexing. My question is if PHP-FPM supports it at a protocol level.

Comment: Maybe https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/highload-php-en/25NebljL7jI will have some insight, though it is a year old.

Comment: It'd be easier if you told us what problem you're trying to solve. What would you achieve if `php-fpm` implemented multiplexing and what would multiplexing help you solve? As far as I know, no HTTP server implements FastCGI multiplexing (maybe something changed since 2014. since I last checked) and I honestly don't see what multiplexing would help at all.

Comment: In a three years old post I've read in the nginx forum it states that the major FastCGI application PHP does not (and probably will never) support multiplexing.

Comment: This is not really a PHP question but a PHP implementation detail question which probably belongs (or should belong) under a different tag.